# GWT RequestFactory on Nebeans

Tags: gwt, netbeans, requestfactory

Hello i have a trouble to run a simple application using RequestFactory i'm using Nebeans    7.3 GWT 2.5.1 deployed on Glassfish server 3.1.2 
I got the following exception when the request is fired 
**SEVERE: Unexpected error 
java.lang.RuntimeException: The RequestFactory ValidationTool must be run for the "xxxx" RequestFactory type**
Has anyone tried that on Netbeans IDE if yes can you provide a link or a pom.xml?
Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

2 steps!
Project->Libraries->Processors add requestfactory-apt.jar
Project->properties->Build->Compiling :check Enable Annotation Processing
save
Clean and Build the Deobfuscator will be generated